# Laravel join 3 tables 1 from different database. Query really slow

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have below code,

```
  $resultsInCalls =  DB::table('log')
        ->join('user_2 as user_old', 'log.agent', '=', 'user_old.sip_id')
        ->join('db2.abc as call_r', 'log.agent', '=', 'call_r.localParty')
        ->select('user_old.fname','user_old.lname','log.data2', 'log.callid', 'call_r.filename')
        ->whereDate('log.created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))    // this day
        ->where('log.data2', '>=', '45')    
        ->where('log.agent', '=', $id)   
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('event', '=', 'COMPLETEAGENT')
               ->orWhere('event', '=', 'COMPLETECALLER');
             }) 
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->take(5)
        ->get();    

          var_dump($resultsInCalls);
```

log and user_2 tables are from same DB.When I run this query it takes too much time. How to join this kind of tables in laravel.

Comment: define `too much time` ? and share `number of rows or data` ?

Comment: @Rishi Raut yes query is working. But it takes so long to run

Comment: Still you need to define `so long` share exact time @Chandimal and no of rows ? like 1000 rows or 10000 rows, 10 Million or more ?

Comment: @Rishi Raut Still running .above 100000 rows. I think my query is wrong. Please help

Comment: You need to share your logic, if there were any error than it would not run for a single rows, you got 5 rows. means, you are hiding something, show whats in your hand ? ;)

Comment: @Rishi Raut is this join correct?  all I can see is query still running and in my tables around 1/2 million data available